# Finding a substring within an array list made from file, java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, substring

I have a text file from which I've created an Array list. Each line = one element of collection. Is there any way to find a specific word in that line, and if it's found, output that line to console? 
Right now that part of my code looks somewhat like this:

```
protected static void FindBook() {
    System.out.print("Author's name: ");
    String neededauthor = sc.nextLine();
    for (int k=0; k<=books.size(); k++) {
        if (books.get(k).contains(neededauthor)) 
            System.out.println(books.get(k)); 
    }
}
```

But it's giving me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Update: I've tried to fix it, and now the exception is gone, but it doesn't work either. After I enter the name, the method stops working and just doesn't do anything, where it should output that line. I don't understand what the matter is

Comment: `k<=books.size()` -> `k<books.size()`

Answer (score 1):

As the other anwers already say, there is a problem when accessing an index that is not there:

```
books.get(books.size())
```

The index runs from `0` to `size()-1`, so `size()` is out of bounds.

You can avoid the index completely and make your code simpler by using a foreach loop like this:

```
for (Book book: books)
    if (book.contains(neededauthor)) 
        System.out.println(book);
```

I assumed that the type of `books` is some collection of type `Book`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code looks correct, but there is one problem.

> for (int k=0; k<=books.size(); k++) {

If `k` starts at 0, it cannot be equal to `books.size()`, because that would mean that it will go through the `for` loop one more time than there are elements in `books.size()`.

Try changing it to `for (int k = 0; k < books.size(); k++) {`

Besides that, if your ArrayList `books` has values in it, your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this part `k<books.size()` instead of `k<=books.size()` it should be only less than. Not less than and equal. Also change your method name to `findBook()` since its not following Java camel notation